# Can an ENS name point to a contract address?

Tags: contract-deployment, ens

I know that an ethereum wallet address can have a ENS (Ethereum Name Service) name, but it is possible for a contract? So instead of giving the contract address is it possible to give the contract's ENS name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes a contract can have an ENS address.

A well known example is the Ethereum Foundation donation contract, which you can look up with `ethereumfoundation.eth`. You can see it at: https://etherscan.io/enslookup-search?search=ethereumfoundation.eth

> The ENS Ethereum Address for this name is 0xfb6916095ca1df60bb79ce92ce3ea74c37c5d359
> Also accessible at ethereumfoundation.eth

Comment: Promoting a token or ICO is gauche. I replaced it with a fairly neutral example of the Ethereum Foundation donation contract.

Answer (score 1):

From [ENS documentation](http://ens.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html). **Architecture.**

> ENS has two principal components: the registry, and resolvers.
>
> The ENS registry consists of a single central contract that maintains
>   a list of all domains and subdomains, and stores three critical pieces
>   of information about each:
>
> The owner of the domain 
> The resolver for the domain 
>  The time-to-live for all records under the domain 
>  
>   **The owner of a domain may be either
>   an external account (a user) or a smart contract**. A registrar is
>   simply a smart contract that owns a domain, and issues subdomains of
>   that domain to users that follow some set of rules defined in the
>   contract.